# Generating an atlas, setHideCoverage doesn't work

Tags: pyqgis, atlas

I'm trying to print my layout.
Sadly, I cannot figure out how to hide the coverage layer.

The `setHideCoverage(True)` - line doesn't change my output

My code so far:

```
project = QgsProject.instance()
manager = project.layoutManager()
layout_name = self.listWidget.currentItem().text()
layout = manager.layoutByName(layout_name)

my_atlas = layout.atlas()
my_atlas.setFilterFeatures(False)

# Starts Layout Generation
my_atlas.setHideCoverage(True)
my_atlas.setEnabled(True)

my_atlas.beginRender()

# For 0 to Number of features in Atlas Selection
for i in range(0, my_atlas.count()):

    # Create Next Layout
    if i < my_atlas.count():
        my_atlas.next()

    # Create exporter Layout for each layout generate with Atlas
    exporter = QgsLayoutExporter(my_atlas.layout())

    print('Saving File: ' + str(my_atlas.currentFeatureNumber() + 1) + ' of ' + str(my_atlas.count()))

    # If you want to create a PNG's files
    exporter.exportToImage(self.pfad + "/" + my_atlas.currentFilename() + ".jpg",
                            QgsLayoutExporter.ImageExportSettings())

    # Show which file is creating
    print('Create File: ' + my_atlas.currentFilename())

# Close Atlas Creation
my_atlas.endRender()
```

Comment: The "setHideCoverage(True)" - line doesnt change my output

Comment: I suspect this may be a bug. The line `my_atlas.setHideCoverage(True)` does indeed hide the coverage layer in the atlas, but exporting the atlas using `QgsLayoutExporter` does not respect this setting. Exporting the atlas via the button in the atlas toolbar does, however.

Comment: The "HideCoverage"-option is alwayse a little buggy. When i want to plot manualy i have to uncheck the option and then check it again. Else it wont work. Thats why i thought maybe i have to refresh the map but that didnt work too.  If i run the script and open the layout after that the options are set correctly AND the covarage layer is hidden. But not in the plot.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, it works this way. But I was still curious how to solve the problem.
And I finally found a solution. When I use flags to change the imageExportSettings` it works.

Here is my final code:

```
project = QgsProject.instance()
manager = project.layoutManager()
layout_name = self.listWidget.currentItem().text()
layout = manager.layoutByName(layout_name)

my_atlas = layout.atlas()
my_atlas.setFilterFeatures(False)

# Starts Layout Generation
my_atlas.setHideCoverage(True)
my_atlas.setEnabled(True)

my_atlas.beginRender()
        
# Create exporter Layout for each layout generate with Atlas
exporter = QgsLayoutExporter(my_atlas.layout())
image_settings = exporter.ImageExportSettings()

# hide Coverage
image_settings.flags = QgsLayoutRenderContext.Flag(QgsLayoutRenderContext.FlagHideCoverageLayer |                              
                        QgsLayoutRenderContext.FlagAntialiasing |
                        QgsLayoutRenderContext.FlagUseAdvancedEffects)

# For 0 to Number of features in Atlas Selection
for i in range(0, my_atlas.count()):

 # Create Next Layout
  if i < my_atlas.count():
     my_atlas.next()

  # Create exporter Layout for each layout generate with Atlas
  exporter = QgsLayoutExporter(my_atlas.layout())

  # If you want to create a PNG's files
  exporter.exportToImage(self.pfad + "/" + my_atlas.currentFilename() + ".jpg",
                        QgsLayoutExporter.ImageExportSettings())


# Close Atlas Creation
my_atlas.endRender()
```

Comment: How to use multiple flags? A: You can use `|` operator. Ex: `flags = flag1 | flag2`

Answer (score 2):

What you can do as a workaround is to set the layer's visibility in the map canvas to `False`. It still works as a coverage layer, but will not show in your atlas exports.

Replace `my_atlas.setHideCoverage(True)` with these lines:

```py
# change 'coverage_layer' to the name of your layer
coverage = project.mapLayersByName('coverage_layer')[0]  
coverage_ltl = project.layerTreeRoot().findLayer(coverage)
coverage_ltl.setItemVisibilityChecked(False)
```

If you want to make it visible after your export, add the inverse at the end of your script:

```py
coverage_ltl.setItemVisibilityChecked(True)
```

If the coverage layer has already been set in the atlas settings, you can use this to avoid having to hard-code the name:

```py
coverage = my_atlas.coverageLayer()
```